# Is Guinness on tap better quality in Ireland?

Tags: taste, brewing, stout, draught

My roommate was born and raised in Ireland, Dublin mostly, and he insists that not only is draught Guinness (never had it from the bottle myself) better tasting in Ireland than Canada, or the States for that matter, but that it's more than just an opinion, that there's a subtly different way of brewing it or that they don't export the best stuff. He was a bartender for years and has 50 some years experience drinking it! Any chance there's actually a better Guinness in Eire, or is it just fresher?